# Check multiple conditions at once TS/JS

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a way to check multiple conditions at once in Typescript?
Instead of:

```
if(something === first || something === second || something === third)
```

Or:

```
if(something === first && something === second && something === third)
```

Is there a way to combind them to something like:

```
if(something === first, second, third)
```

I know that the comma operator is not the answer, but this is just an example.

Comment: I would suggest to use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types).

Comment: how can (something === first && something === second && something === third) happen?

Comment: @ABOS It's just an example; A more common usage is ||.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for your first example, or [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for your second example:

```js
// checking if any of them are equal
if ([first, second, third].some(ele => ele === something))

// checking if all of them are equal
if ([first, second, third].every(ele => ele === something))
```

For your first example specifically, you can actually use [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
if ([first, second, third].includes(something))
```

Comment: Not exactly what I had in mind as it makes the line longer and less readable, but I guess it can be an alternative.

Comment: @Questioneering I've edited my answer to include a more readable alternative to `some`. Sadly, I can't think of one for `every`.